# How to get the parent of an element

Tags: dom, protractor, end-to-end

For example, I am randomly picking a `button` element from within the rows of a `table`.
After the `button` is found, I want to retrieve the `table`'s row which contains a selected button.

Heres is my code snippet:

```
browser.findElements(by.css('[ng-click*=submit]')).then(function (results) {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length);
  var row = results[randomNum];
         // ^ Here I want to get the parent of my random button
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Decided to use xpath.

```
var row = results[randomNum].findElement(by.xpath('ancestor::tr'));
```

Comment: `by.xpath('..')` would also give you the parent element.

Comment: Does this work anymore? I can't see any reference to xpath in the docs now.

Comment: @mariachimike you have probably figure this out by now but for future searchers, i am on protractor 1.3.0 and 'element(by.xpath('..'))' still works. The current latest version is 1.3.1 and the changelog only includes one fix so it will work in that as well, i cant imagine it would be taken out in the near future if ever.

Comment: Failed: element(...).findElement is not a function

Answer (score 44):

As of the most recent Protractor (1.6.1 as of this writing), the syntax changed a bit:

```
var row = results[randomNum].element(by.xpath('..'));
```

(use `element()` instead of `findElement()`).

Answer (score 10):

You can now use

`var element = element(by.css('.foo')).getWebElement()
var parentElement = element.getDriver()  // gets the parent element`

to get the parent element.  See http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getDriver for more info.

Comment: The other answers are outdated (though still functional), this one works great and is more concise.  Thanks!

Comment: Failed: element(...).getDriver is not a function

Comment: @Justin thanks for pointing that out!  It looks like Protractor was updated to require using `getWebElement()` to call getDriver().  I updated my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, at the moment there is an easier way to select the parent of an element avoiding to use `xpath`.
From an `ElementFinder` you can simply access the parent element through `parentElementArrayFinder` and for example then trigger directly the `click` method:

`myElement.parentElementArrayFinder.click();`